# How do I indicate an active nav-item in a common header?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a header that I plan to use on the top of all my pages. I'd like to keep it in a separate file (something I'm used to doing with `php`, but I'm new to the world of Bootstrap); however, I am not sure how I would handle dynamically assigning the `active` class to the `nav-item` that represents the current page. Does Bootstrap (4) have a baked-in solution for this sort of thing? I've been searching around but haven't found a good solution yet. Thanks in advance!

```html
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-transparent fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Work</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Handling the assignment of the active nav item, presumably based on the current URL/route is something you're gonna have to handle with php (as you suggested). Basically, you'd have a php-injected script in the file to determine which link should have the `active` class applied, like `class="<?php $condition ? "active" : "" ?>" ...`. That gets tricky when the file is in it's own `js` file, as you can't use `php` tags in them.

Comment: @TimLewis - Thanks, Tim. Yeah, this would be a breeze with `php`. I guess I'm shooting to learn the Bootstrap approach to this, if there is one. Then again, maybe I'll just need some sort of outside solution (php, jquery, etc.)

Comment: Bootstrap is unlikely to have any kind of solution to this, being a CSS framework. By that I mean you can use Bootstrap standalone without a development server (apache, npm, etc) and still have everything work statically with plain HTML, CSS and js/jQuery.

Comment: @TimLewis - Ah. I see. Ok, looks like I'll go with `php` or poke around looking at other approaches. Thanks!

Comment: How would a client side code know which page is active. Thats the server's job to tell what to display. If you are looking for an `active` class you can apply, well just add the `active` as a class, when your PHP code updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap includes some jQuery and is not just CSS.  However, you can always run some JavaScript or jQuery on page load that toggles the class based on reading an element when the page is loaded. For example you could:

1) have an identifier on each page (eg. class name inside an element on a page that holds the page's name/value).  Example:

```html
<h1 class="page-lookup">
 Home
</h1>
```

2) set you jQuery in a function to read for class and grab the value of the element with a .val().  Example:

```js
const activePage = $(".page-lookup").val()
```

3) Add an id on each

in your navbar to uniquely identify them. Example:

```html
<li id="home-page" class="nav-item"> 
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
</li>
```

4) Run a switch case that looks up the stored value (activePage) for a match.  In the case that matches you can run jQuery to update the class to include the "active" syntax that will trigger Bootstrap's formatting.

Example:

```js
switch (activePage) {
    case Home:
        $('#home-page).attr("class", "nav-item active");
        break;
    case About:
        $('#about-page).attr("class", "nav-item active");
        break;
    }
```